# alternative to findById using passport in nodejs authentication?

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, passport.js

I am using passport to authenticate a user. My node.js server is working as a proxy server for another server; I can send an authenticate request to the other server to verify that the user and the password are correct.

I am having trouble with the function I need to include inside my deserializeUser, because the other server doesn't include any way to search for a given user by id.

First, here are my serialize and deserialize functions. Note that I am using the username as my identifier.

```
passport.serializeUser(function(user, done) {
    done(null, user.username);
});

//used to deserialize the user from the session
passport.deserializeUser(function(username, done) {
    user.findByUsername(username, function(err, user) {
        done(err, user);
    });
});
```

For the local strategy, here is my code:

```
passport.use('local-login', new LocalStrategy({
    //use the fields for username and password
    usernameField : 'username',
    passwordField : 'password',
    passReqToCallback : true
},
function(req, username, password, done) {
    var loginUser  = new User('username', 'password');
    loginUser.authenticate(function(err, user) {
        if(!user)
            return done(null, false, req.flash('loginMessage', 'No user found.'));

        return done(null, user);
}));
```

the authenticate function is defined as follows(pseudocode included for brevity):

```
function(callback) {
    //make a call to the external server with this.username and this.password as credentials
    //if error
    callback(err, null)
    //if the external server verifies the call,
    callback(null, user)
}
```

What should I use in my deserializeUser?

Also, I don't even understand why deserializeUser needs a user object. Isn't it just extracting the user from the session? Or is that a fundamental misunderstanding on my part?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `deserializeUser` function takes the user identifier (which is stored in the session), and uses it to get your full user object from your user store, in order to populate the user member of your express request object.

This is useful because you probably don't want to store your full user object in the session, just a reference to it, and then you can go get the full object from your database or other user store on each request.

Using a username for the identifier in `serializeUser` and `deserializeUser` seems like it should work, as long as the identifier is consistent between the two.

As far as serializing the user object out of your separate store -- the contents of that user object are mostly for *your* convenience.  If you have code in some of your routes that will want to check some property of the user, this is the place to put it.  If your code doesn't need to know anything other than that it's a valid user, your user object can just be `{username: username}`.

--

So, in your example you mention that your external server is only able to validate that usernames and passwords are correct, and gives you a token back.  If you have no other separate store of information about the users, that means that the only information your app will want to retain about the user is that they have authenticated and what their username and token are.

Then your local strategy would look something like:

```
passport.use('local-login', new LocalStrategy({ 
    //use the fields for username and password 
    usernameField : 'username', 
    passwordField : 'password', 
    passReqToCallback : true 
  }, 
  function(req, username, password, done) { 
    somehowAuthenticateWithMyExternalServer(username, password, function(isValid, token) { 
    if(!isValid) 
      return done(null, false, req.flash('loginMessage', 'No user found.')); 
    return done(null, { username: username, token: token }); 
  }); 
}));
```

Since you want to just keep this user object in the session instead of serializing it off anywhere, your serialize/deserialize functions can just be trivial pass-throughs:

```
passport.serializeUser(function(user, done) { 
    done(null, user); 
}); 

//used to deserialize the user from the session 
passport.deserializeUser(function(user, done) { 
    done(null, user); 
});
```

(maybe it is possible to omit these all together in this case, not sure)

Then if any of your routes examine at the `req.user` object, its only properties will be `username` and 'token.

Comment: I don't have a behavior that I am seeing; it is one of my requirements. It is working for using the username as my identifier. The problem that I'm running into is that I don't have access to the store containing the users. There is no way for me to retrieve a user object based off of an identifier; I can only send it a username and a password and it will tell me if it is valid.

Comment: or am i supposed to retrieve my user object from my express session store? I am so confused.

Comment: I've updated the answer above to try to clarify that part, let me know if it helps. :-)

Comment: Thanks, that makes it clearer. However, how do I store additional info in the session? let's say I want to store a username, a token, and a hashed password, and then retrieve those three from the session every time I deserialize. Is that possible?

Comment: Because that is what my userobject should be; I'd like to retrieve that all from the session if possible with a deserialize.

Comment: If I'm understanding your need correctly, you would just have your deserialize function return a user object that looks like `{ username: username, token: token, passwordHash: passwordHash }`.  Then req.user.token would contain the token, etc.   (note however, that deserialize would be the place where you look these values up from your external store and put them in the session, not a place where you retrieve anything from the session as you mentioned)

Comment: well, where would i get the username, token, and passwordHash from? how do i serialize all 3 of those in the serialize function?

in the deserialize, you mention that it is the place where I would look these values from external store, but I do not have an external store. Do I need to implement one? would redis work for that? Can't I proceed without implementing an external store, and instead just retrieving the user object from the session itself?

Thanks!

Comment: I guess I am missing something here.  In your original statement you mentioned that you had an external server which is where you would check your passwords.  If that is literally all it can do for you, and you aren't tracking users any other way, than your user object should probably just be `{username: username}`.  In this scenario you shouldn't have to deal with a token or passwordHash on the user object -- your authenticate function will get a username and password, and be responsible for validating it or not.  If validated, it will return '{ username: username }' as the user object.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/60582/discussion-between-ploer-and-bassel).